# select by priority

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Structure :

Registration :

```
uuid | name | total
```

Rate :

```
uuid | type | rate
```

Registration_Rate :

```
registration | rate
```

Initial Request is :

```
select * from registration r
join registration_rate rr on rr.registration = r.uuid
join rate rt on rt.uuid = rr.rate
group by r.name,  rt.type
```

My SQL result from two table (registration & rate ) is :

```
  uuid | name | rate | type
     1 | AAA  | 15   | U
     2 | BBB  | 20   | U
     3 | CCC  | 300  | F
     4 | AAA  | 250  | F
```

I would like to have something like this (if a rate's type 'F' exists then display instead)

```
  uuid | name | rate | type
     2 | BBB  | 20   | U
     3 | CCC  | 300  | F
     4 | AAA  | 250  | F
```

Thanks

**Edited :**

I have tried another solution which works

```
select uuid, name, rate, (case rt.type when 2 then 2 else 1 end ) as type
from registration r
join registration_rate rr on rr.registration = r.uuid
join rate rt on rt.uuid = rr.rate
group by r.name,  rt.type
```

Comment: and your table schema is ... ? and your current query is ... ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? it is quite fuzzy what you are asking

Comment: I have edited my post. How to do a conditional request based on rate's type value ?

Comment: you still did not provide your tables structure. which table belongs `id` column from result?  what is aggregate functions you are trying to get when `GROUP BY`?

Comment: your table structure not matching to your query: `registration` table has no `uuid`  but according to your query it should: `rr.registration = r.uuid`; `Registration_Rate` table has no column `registration` as well. try to play with this draft fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5b3d and when it will be ready provide us the fiddle. you should implement `INSERT` data

Comment: uuid = id, sorry. Yes, is not idRegistration. My first request works, not is the problem.

Comment: the problem is your question which is not clear and not fully prepared

Comment: so we have no `id` in any of our tables. where it came from to your result then?

Comment: However , others have understood my questions but I would just know if a conditional select  was possible not remake my model. Thanks

Comment: `uuid` is ambiguous in your query. and you still did not explain what is the goal for `GROUP BY`

Comment: try to get fiddle working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bd99a/3

Answer (score 0):

If it's an F row return it. Or, use `NOT EXISTS` to verify no other row with same name has an F.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where type = 'F'
   or not exists (select * from tablename t2
                  where t2.name = t1.name
                    and t2.type = 'F')
```

Alternative solution:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
    join (select name, min(type) type
          from tablename
          group by name) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name and t1.type = t2.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I suggest main idea)

```
 SELECT t.uuid, 
       t.name, 
       IFNULL(MAX(t.F_type), MAX(t.not_F_type)) AS "type", 
       IFNULL(MAX(t.F_rate), MAX(t.not_F_rate)) AS "rate"
FROM
(
    SELECT r.uuid, 
           r.name,
           CASE rt.type WHEN 'F' THEN rt.type END AS F_type, 
           CASE WHEN rt.type <> 'F' THEN rt.type END AS not_F_type,
           CASE rt.type WHEN 'F' THEN rt.rate END AS F_rate, 
           CASE WHEN rt.type <> 'F' THEN rt.rate END AS not_F_rate
    FROM registration AS r
    JOIN registration_rate AS rr ON rr.registration = r.uuid
    JOIN rate AS rt ON rt.uuid = rr.rate
) as t
GROUP BY t.uuid, t.name;
```

So, you need to split appropriate columns ("rate", "type") according to your rule (if a rate's type 'F' exists then display instead of others) into two new separate columns using case statement: the first column contains value for F type and the second one contains value for others types. I did it for "type" and "rate" columns. Then I glued together these columns (and records) using group by, aggregation functions and IFNULL statement (you can use others statement here: case, IF, etc).

As I understand the question, this is what you need.